# Makefile - compiling back and forth

Tags: makefile, fortran90

Following is the directory structure of my project:

```
                       expt-main
                       ---------
                       Makefile_main
                    /             \
         subdir-1                    subdir-2
         --------                    --------
         Makefile_1                  Makefile_2
         mod_codeA.f90               mod_code1.f90
         mod_codeB.f90               mod_code2.f90
         mod_codeC.f90               mod_code3.f90
```

Makefile_main:

```
export

SHELL = /bin/sh

F90     = mpxlf95

SRCDIRS = $(subdir-1) $(subdir-2)

all:
        @for DIR in ${SRCDIRS} ;

          do \
            back=`pwd`; \
            cd $$DIR ;\
            $(MAKE) ; status=$$? ; \
            if [ $$status != 0 ] ; then \
              echo "Exit status fro make was $$status" ; exit $$status ; \
            fi ; \
            cd $$back ; \
         done

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Makefile-1:

%.o: %.f90
        $(F90) $(F90FLAGS) -I$(subdir-2) -c $<

mod_codeA.o: mod_codeC.o $(subdir-2)/mod_code2.o

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Makefile-2:

PROG = $(exec)

subdir-1_objs = $(subdir-1)/mod_codeA.o mod_codeB.o mod_codeC.o

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(subdir-2_objs) $(subdir-1_objs) -o $@ $(subdir-2_objs) $(subdir-1_objs)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

I've written the Makefile_main such that it compiles the codes (modules) in subdir-1 first and then the ones in subdir-2 and finally makes the executable. The issue: modules in subdir-1 uses modules from subdir-2 and in similar fashion, modules in subdir-2 uses those in subdir-1. My make is getting failed because the modules being used is in other directory. How to write a makefile which will take care of this issue that is, while compiling modules in subdir-1, whenever it encounters the need for an object file from subdir-2, it should switch to subdir-2 compile the necessary modules and return back to subdir-1 for further action?

Comment: Oops! I deleted my older Qs :( I hope my recent Q gives the entire picture :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If modules in different subdirectories need each other as you say, then this is not a good use of recursive Make.

Do away with `Makefile-1` and `Makefile-2`, and let `Makefile_main` do all the work. (I can't tell you specifically how to change `Makefile-main`, since I don't do Fortran, I don't understand `Makefile-2`, and I don't see any dependency of modules in subdir-2 upon those in subdir-1).

Comment: Thanks Beta! The two sub-directories are two separate models that I am trying to integrate depending on a logic switch. Therefore, it won't be a clean way of combining the two sub-directories into one. The Makefile-2:


PROG = $(exec)


subdir-1_objs = $(subdir-1)/mod_codeA.o mod_codeB.o mod_codeC.o


all: $(PROG)


$(PROG): $(subdir-2_objs) $(subdir-1_objs) -o $@ $(subdir-2_objs) $(subdir-1_objs)


mod_code1: mod_code3.o $(subdir-1)/mod_codeA.o
___________________________________________________________________

Comment: @jkp, you don't have to combine the directories. Just combine the makefiles.

Comment: Thanks Beta! Have read the paper suggested by Massimiliano and understood what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to this directory layout and still keep three separated Makefiles, then you can use compiler flags to instruct the FORTRAN compiler to put module files into a common directory of your choice.

For instance using:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

you can use `-I` and `-J` flags to instruct the compiler on:

1. where to search for module files (.mod)
2. where to put generated module files

That said I think that the suggestion given by [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896619/771663) to join the Makefiles makes a lot of sense. To know some of the reasons why you should do that you can read [this paper](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf).

Finally, as your project seems not to be very large at this stage, I also suggest to take into consideration [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/project/about.html) as a build system, as it possibly provides a more convenient way of specifying dependencies between targets (as well as many other things).

Comment: @Beta &@Massimiliamo: The directory structure I described above is only a sample of my project. Indeed the project is very large: subdir-1 (200+ files) and subdir-2 (400+ files). The task is to combine two models which were built at separate centres and hence they have different rules (compilers, compiler & linking options) for building. I'll go through the paper and I am also working on suggestion given by Beta. But preferably, I am keen on having separate makefiles. Right now, I am looking into the possibility of making a soft link of all the codes in 1 dir and then using a single makefile.

Comment: @Massimiliamo:Can you please elaborate on the first part of your soultion (... use compiler flags ...)

Comment: @jkp You could use a rule like `gfortran -I<mypathtomodules> -J<mypathtomodules> ...`. The part `-I<mypathtomodules>` tells `gfortran` to look for .mod in `<mymodulepath>`, while `-J<mypathtomodules>` tells `gfortran` to put .mod files in `<mymodulepath>`.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the paper and is informative. Will now work on making a single makefile.